# How to update highscore

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am having score and highscore in my game in a collision property so whenever my object collides on a certain logic score and highscore increases  as I dont have die stage yet in my game so when I relaunch my game highscore starts from zero I wanted that highscore should start from the previous highscore and only be updated if score>highscore. I have written code for it but it is not working when my object collides highscore starts from 6 so kindly tell me the way to solve it

```
   local Highscore = 0
    score = 0
    local function updateText()
        HighscoreText.text = "Highscore: " .. Highscore
    end

-- collision Property --

 local function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
-- logic --

    -- score update--

-- highscore update--
if score > Highscore then
  Highscore = score 
end
updateText()


end
end
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "collision" , onCollision )

end
```

Comment: Use [Simple-Table-Load-Save-Functions-for-Corona-SDK](https://github.com/robmiracle/Simple-Table-Load-Save-Functions-for-Corona-SDK) - Two very simple load and save function to store a Lua Table and Read it back in. Requires the Corona SDK JSON Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a small module that handles persistence for your high score using the Corona SDK JSON Library.

```
-- File name
local fileName = "highscore.json"
-- Path for File
-- The system.DocumentsDirectory will be backed up by synchronization in iOS
local pathForFile = system.pathForFile(fileName, system.DocumentsDirectory)

-- JSON library included in Corona SDK
local json = require( "json" )

-- This table holds two functions
-- persistHighscore, to save the highscore to file
-- fetchHighscore, to retrieve the saved highscore
local persistence = {}

-- Persists the highscore table
-- It receives only one parameter which must be a table
-- containing the highscore in a Key, Value pair
-- Example: {highscore = 10}
persistence.persistHighscore = function(highscoreTable)
    local encoded = json.encode( highscoreTable )
    local file, errorString = io.open( pathForFile, "w" )

    if not file then
        print("Opening file failed: " .. errorString)
    else
        file:write(encoded)
        file:flush()
        file:close()
    end
end

-- Returns the Highscore table
-- If there is a highscore file it will be read and a 
--table containing the highscore will be returned
persistence.fetchHighscore = function()
    local decoded, pos, msg = json.decodeFile( pathForFile )
    if not decoded then
        print( "Decode failed at "..tostring(pos)..": "..tostring(msg) )
    else
        print( "File successfully decoded!" )
        return decoded
    end
end

return persistence
```

In your project:

```
local persistence = require("highscorePeristence")
```

If you're not familiar with module loading in Corona SDK with Lua be sure to
check this: 
[Corona SDK API Doc - require](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/package/require.html)
In your high score handling logic when you find out that the score is higher than the current highscore:

```
if score > highscore then
    -- Container table to be stored in JSON
    local scoreTable = {
        highscore=score
        }
    persistence.persistHighscore(scoreTable)
end
```

And when you're loading the project and you want to load the stored highscore:

```
local highscore
local scoreTable = persistence.fetchHighscore()
-- No highscore was stored
if not scoreTable then
    -- Initialize the highscore with 0 since there was no other value before
    highscore = 0
else
    -- Initialize the highscore with the value read from the JSON decoded table
    highscore = scoreTable.highscore
end
```